# Proper way of nesting async/await methods

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following scenario:

```
async method1() {
  await method2() {...}

  method3().then(x => {
    await method4().then({...}).catch({...})
  }).catch({...})
}
```

My node compiler threw an error saying that await cannot be used on a method outside of an async method.
The error was pointed at the `await method4()`. May I just double confirm my understanding that because the `method4()` execution context is within `method3()`, therefore, if i wanted to use an await on `method4()`, i need to make `method3()` async? But then that is not possible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to not mix `.then()` and `await` as it just complicates things.  And, in general, you should NOT make a `.then()` handler be `async` as that's a sign of the above mixing which is not necessary.  So, you can just do this:

```
async method1() {
  await method2(...)
  try {
      let x = await method3();
      await method4();
  } catch(e) {
      ...
  }
}
```

Note: I did not put the call to `await method2()` inside the try/catch only because you weren't directly handling errors on it in your code, leaving any rejections in it to go back to the caller which this will also do.  But, if you want to locally handle errors from the call to `method2()`, then put it inside the try/catch also:

```
async method1() {
  try {
      await method2(...)
      let x = await method3();
      await method4();
  } catch(e) {
      ...
  }
}
```

Note: This assumes that all these methods are asynchronous and return a promise.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the callback inside method3().then() as **async** function. So that you can use **await** inside of that.

```
async method1() {
  await method2() {...}

  method3().then(async x => {
      await method4().then({...}).catch({...})
  }).catch({...})
 }
```

Also, you need not to use await, if you are using then and catch.

You can convert it to,

```
const res = await method4();
```

The variable **res** will contain result or error msg.
Also it's better to wrap the await statements inside try-catch block

Comment: In general, it is better to NOT mix `.then()` and `await`.  If you're inside an `async` function, then just use `await` instead of `.then()`.  You can use `try/catch` for error handling with `await`.

Comment: Thanks DJ Hemath, i picked the answer below because in terms of code design, it is a lot cleaner, but I did learn something from you as well. Did not know i could do async x.